# Optimizing this cases-command for inline expresions

Tags: matrices, inline

I'd like to optimize the following command

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\casos}[2]{\left.\begin{cases}
                        #1 \\ #2
                       \end{cases} \mkern-18mu \right\}}

\begin{document}
\ldots demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $ \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}$ durch
\[\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}=\casos{+\cos \theta}{-\sin\theta}\]
gegeben.
\end{document}
```

I'd like to become more sublte (thiner?) curly brackets (here perhaps looks ok, but in case one uses only one character, the brackets seem a little to big). Also the in-line version is not smaller than the one in the equation. But the only way to implement it, so far, was for me `cases`, as you can see.

[image]:

Comment: in the usual terminology, the term `cases` implies that there's a brace on only one side of the stacked expressions.  since you want braces on both sides, it's better to think of this as a matrix.  a couple of the answers do make this distinction.

Comment: Thanks, barbara beeton. I changed the tag. It's all I can do, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made a number of strategic changes.  I dispensed with the `cases` environment.  I built the stacked math using a `\stackanchor` (from `stackengine` package).

I used the `\stretchleftright{}{}{}` macro (from `scalerel` package) to make the braces  by stretching the `\{` and `\}` glyphs, subject to a maximum aspect ratio limitation.

To achieve a different look inline (text style) versus in display style, I used a `\mathchoice` to select the proper form.

In the MWE, I show two versions, giving variation to the maximum brace aspect ratio and the inline stacking gap. I made the `\textstyle` version `\small`, though perhaps `\footnotesize` might be preferable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath

\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\maxaspect{300}
\def\shortgap{1pt}
% \displaystyle VERSION
\newcommand{\dcasos}[2]{\def\stacktype{L}\strutlongstacks{T}%
  \stretchleftright[\maxaspect]{\{}{\stackanchor{#1}{#2}}{\}}}
%%% AN ALTERNATIVE USING TRADITIONAL \left \right SYNTAX FOR \displaystyle
%%\newcommand{\dcasos}[2]{\def\stacktype{L}\strutlongstacks{T}\left\{\stackanchor{#1}{#2}\right\}}
% \textstyle VERSION
\newcommand{\tcasos}[2]{\def\stacktype{S}\setstackgap{S}{\shortgap}\small%
  \stretchleftright[\maxaspect]{\{}{\stackanchor{#1}{#2}}{\}}}
\newcommand\casos[2]{\mathchoice{\dcasos{#1}{#2}}
                                {\tcasos{#1}{#2}}
                                {\tcasos{#1}{#2}}
                                {\tcasos{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\ldots demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $ \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}$ durch
\[\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}=\casos{+\cos \theta}{-\sin\theta}\]
gegeben.

\def\maxaspect{200}
\def\shortgap{3pt}
\ldots demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $ \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}$ durch
\[\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos{\sin \theta}{ \cos \theta}=\casos{+\cos \theta}{-\sin\theta}\]
gegeben.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Putting together Zarko's and Steven's ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\casos}[3][c]{{\mathpalette\docasos{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}

\newcommand{\docasos}[2]{\dodocasos{#1}#2}

\newcommand{\dodocasos}[4]{%
  \left\{%
  \begin{\ifx\displaystyle#1\else small\fi matrix*}[#2]
    #3\\
    #4
  \end{\ifx\displaystyle#1\else small\fi matrix*}
  \right\}%
}

\begin{document}

demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $\casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ durch
\[
\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\casos{\cos\theta}{-\sin\theta}
\]
gegeben.

demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $\casos[l]{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ durch
\[
\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos[l]{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\casos[l]{\cos\theta}{-\sin\theta}
\]
gegeben.

demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $\casos[r]{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ durch
\[
\frac{d}{d\theta} \casos[r]{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\casos[r]{\cos\theta}{-\sin\theta}
\]
gegeben.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if exist an environment which has different layout in `in-line math` and `displaymath`, so I suggest to define two commands, one -- \cases -- for inline use and -- \Cases -- for use in `displaymath`. Instead of `cases` i suggest to use `mathtoo`l and `Bmatrix*` and `Bsmallmatrix*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\Casos}[2]{\begin{Bmatrix*}[r]
                        #1 \\ #2
                       \end{Bmatrix*}}
\newcommand{\casos}[2]{\begin{Bsmallmatrix*}[r]
                        #1 \\ #2
                       \end{Bsmallmatrix*}}

\usepackage[active,textmath,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{figure}
    \ldots demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $\casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ durch
    \[
\frac{d}{d\theta} \Casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\Casos{\cos\theta}{-\sin\theta}
    \]
    gegeben.
\end{figure}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Since compilation of your code gives me error, i change my MWE to article and use preview. 
[image]

**Edit:**
Before of Steven answer I was not aware of \mathchoice. With it my suggestion can be simplified in:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \newcommand{\displaycasos}[2]{\begin{Bmatrix*}[r]
                            #1 \\ #2
                           \end{Bmatrix*}}
    \newcommand{\textcasos}[2]{\begin{Bsmallmatrix*}[r]
                            #1 \\ #2
                           \end{Bsmallmatrix*}}
    \newcommand\casos[2]{\mathchoice{\displaycasos{#1}{#2}}
                                    {\textcasos{#1}{#2}}
                                    {\textcasos{#1}{#2}}
                                    {\textcasos{#1}{#2}}}

       \begin{document}
        \ldots demzufolge ist die Ableitung von $\casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ durch
        \[
    \frac{d}{d\theta} \casos{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\casos{\cos\theta}{-\sin\theta}
        \]
        gegeben.
    \end{document}
```